# How to print key and value in an array of array with bash script

Tags: bash

I've this script: an array of array, and a loop. Inside the loop, how can I print the key (foo) and the value (bar)???

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A combo=()
combo+=(['foo']='bar')
combo+=(['hello']='world')
for window in ${combo[@]};
do
    echo ???
    echo ???
done
exit
```

expected output:

```
key: foo   value: bar
key: hello value:world
```

---

I'll read this [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) asap!!

Comment: This won't work how you think it will, `combo` will have one array element that is `barworld`

Comment: Exactly, ... can you help to define array, ed loop through it?

Comment: What exactly is it you are trying to do? Post expected output. Are you trying to make an array inside another ?

Comment: Yes, ... I need a key, and its value. Is this the correct way to define it?

Comment: @JID While you are correct that's only because they didn't declare the array with `declare -A`. If they did this would do what they expected. So a more constructive version of your comment here (and on the posted answer) would likely have been more useful.

Comment: @EtanReisner Yeah probably, i was going to suggest that after working out exactly what OP wanted as i wasn't 100% from the question. As for the answer it is wrong, they have literally just explained how to access a normal array.

Comment: It is "wrong" in as much as the OP is wrong (re: `-A`) and a single character fixes the other issue. Again a more constructive comment would have been useful (even just to explain why it was wrong).

Comment: It is OK for OP to be wrong though as they are asking a question. That wrong comment was more of a sign to others.They posted an answer as though it is correct when if they had tested it they would have seen it was intrinsically wrong. And adding a `declare -A` would not have fixed it as they also didn't use the indirection `!` on the array.

Comment: **note:** the when assigning to associated arrays there is never a need to quote `key` in e.g. `array+=( [key]='some value with spaces' )`. **key** cannot contain more than 1 word unless `IFS` is changed. (that would defeat the purpose of quoting `key` to begin with...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your script is *almost* correct. As is v.coder's answer.

You need to declare your array as an associative one before you append items to it with string keys.

```
declare -A combo
```

Then you need to iterate over the keys of the array (`${!combo[@]}"`) instead of the values (`${combo[@]}"`).

Then the rest of v.coder's answer works just fine.

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A combo
combo+=(['foo']='bar')
combo+=(['hello']='world')
for window in "${!combo[@]}"
do
    echo "${window}" # foo
    echo "${combo[${window}]}" # bar
done
```

Comment: Could you also tell me why first element added is the last printed? I got "hello world" and then "foo bar". Is += the wrong way?

Comment: Associative arrays don't have an order.

Comment: Nice =(. But, ... could you tell me how to iterate the for from the end to the beginning?

Comment: There isn't a "beginning" or an "end" to an associative array. Not in the way you mean. Insertion order doesn't matter.